# Laravel Artisan _ command restarts itself AND stop after twenty minutes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks, laravel-artisan

I have a question about the "*command*" of the Laravel artisan.

When I execute my command (massive adding data to a database with long processing processes), **it stops after about twenty minutes** without being finished.

Moreover, after about twenty insertions, **the command restarts itself** without being finished and restarts the process of adding data (it is variable, sometimes after 15 records).

To be clear, when executing the command, I don't do a cron like "*->everyminute()*'.

Do you have an idea to solve this problem? **Is it a memory, timeout, cron or synchronicity problem ?**

Thank you to you
Have a good day

Comment: Hard to say anything without your code

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz but it's not a code problem. When I insert one record it's work well but with a lot of records, the process crashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you need a Job which you dispatch in the console command and then run it in a redis queue.

then start the queue with this command line

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --timeout=0
```

This should fix your problem

Comment: I'll try with these parameters. Thank you.

Comment: welcome :) please give me feedback if that works for you :)

Comment: Yep sure , i will give you a feedback